# String concatenation in LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to create a `Where` lambda on the concatenation of two string fields, such that it will do it properly in SQL? Say I have a person, and there are two fields, `FirstName` and `LastName`. I want to be able to filter by their full name, which is shown on the page as `FirstName + LastName`.

I can't use a combined property like `FullName` in the linq lambda, because SQL has no idea what that is, and throws an error. I could have it run the query first by using `.AsEnumerable()` before the `Where` but that's less efficient (I think?)

I tried `.Where(p => (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(filterText))`, and this runs without error, but it actually can only filter on one at a time. It's like the resulting sql says `WHERE FirstName LIKE %text% OR LastName LIKE %text%`, rather than searching the concatenation. This means that I can't have my filter text span across the first and last names. If I search for `"hn Do"` in `"John Doe"`, I get no results.

So is there a correct way to do this in LINQ or do I have to settle for an alternate solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
.Where(p => (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(filterText))
```

Otherwise, you're checking "hn Do" against "JohnDoe", which of course will not match.

#### PS

It is not a bug in LINQ to SQL. Your query very clearly asks for an expected behavior that you are not looking for.

#### PPS

It's pretty easy to see what SQL your LINQ query generates using LINQPad. In the case of your original query, it produces something like the following:

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%hn Do%'

SELECT [t0].[PersonId], ...
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[FirstName] + [t0].[LastName]) LIKE @p0
```

Comment: WOW I'm a dumb@$$. For some reason the space crossed my mind for a few seconds and then I dismissed it. Shame is all on me. You'll get the accept as soon as the time lets me.

Comment: @Tesserex: Don't be too hard on yourself. Everyone makes mistakes. The key is to realize that 99.9% of the time you think it's a bug with the framework used by tens of thousands of developers worldwide... it's probably just your code. ;-)

Comment: Yes that definitely is the case. But I suppose it *would* have been a bug, if I were correct in the first place.